# how can I use strcmp_function

Tags: c++, string, function

I write a function for finding a specific word in a text, but I have a problem, I use strcmp_function that gets const char argument, while a[] is not cons char. how can I use this function in this program?(w means word)

```
int comparision(const char sentence[ ],char *w)
{
int i, length=0, c=0, l=0;
int j,count=0;
char a[20]={'0'};
length= strlen(sentence);
l= strlen(w);
for (i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    if (sentence[i] == ' '||sentence[i] == '\t'||sentence[i] == '\n')   
    {
    for(j=0;j<l;j++)
        a[j]=sentence[j+i+1];
    a[j+1]='\0';
if( strcmp(a,w)==0)
    count++;
    }}
return count;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your compiler error?  A character array and character pointer have the same signature in C++.

Comment: `strcmp` is C, not C++. Its supported for backward compatibility. But, if you have `std::string`, why you don't use string? Its secure, RAII-based (No new/delete) and has a lot of predefined powerfull methods (Coparison included). Your code is a simple `string1 == string2` if you use string.

Answer (score 0):

You have this function:

```
  int comparision(const char sentence[ ],char *w)
```

In an argument list for a function, a parameter declared with array like syntax as you do here is really a pointer. The above function declaration is exactly the same as

```
int comparision(const char *sentence,char *w)
```

Even if it was an array, the name of an array when used as an expression is the same as a pointer to the first element in an array- so that works out fine.

That means you can do this:

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
char *str2  = "Hello";

int equal = strcmp(str1, str2) == 0;
```

when passing str1 to strcmp, str1 is said to decay to a pointer, so it is 
exactly the same as doing

```
int equal = strcmp(&str1[0], str2) == 0;
```

`&str[0]` is a pointer to the first element in str1, and has the type `char *`

i.e. your use of strcmp is fine.
This should answer your question - you also mention you have a problem , but not what the problem  is or what you intend to do, so ....

Comment: You're use of grammar is not fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to do something like

```
   int i = 0;
   while (sentence[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (strncmp(&sentence[i], word, l) == 0)
         {
            count += 1;
            i += l;
         }
      else
          i += 1;
    }
    return (count);
```

And you want have any problems since you strncmp just read the array